# Why doesn't the "having" clause work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the following query:

```
select count(distinct email_address) 
from 
(
select distinct email_address, 
case when elq_activity_type='EmailSend' then 1 else 0 end 'Sends', 
case when elq_activity_type='Bounceback' then 1 else 0 end 'Bounces', 
case when elq_activity_type='EmailOpen' then 1 else 0 end 'Opens', 
case when elq_activity_type='EmailClickthrough' then 1 else 0 end 'Clicks' 
from elq_stg_activity
) a
having sum(sends-bounces)>0
```

The having clause doesn't seem to be doing anything. What am I doing wrong?
Need to get all unique emails that had an email delivered to them (send-bounce).
Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: From where sends-bounces column is coming? Can you please provide sample data or table structure?

Comment: Will do, but I am asking from a syntax perspective, I get same output with or without the having clause. or even if I put having something else >0 like clicks (which should be at most 10% of sends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select count(email_address) 
from (select email_address, 
             sum(case when elq_activity_type = 'EmailSend' then 1 else 0 end) Sends, 
             sum(case when elq_activity_type = 'Bounceback' then 1 else 0 end) as Bounces, 
             sum(case when elq_activity_type = 'EmailOpen' then 1 else 0 end) as Opens, 
             sum(case when elq_activity_type = 'EmailClickthrough' then 1 else 0 end) as Clicks 
      from elq_stg_activity
      group by email_address
     ) a
where sends = bounces;
```

There are numerous issues with your query.  This is the only sensible interpretation I could think of.

Comment: I'll check it out but send-bounce= delivered which is what I am looking for. all those that had an email delivered. not send>bounce because a user can be sent many emails

Comment: select count(distinct email_address) ... where sends-bounces>0 worked! thank you